# How do I only keep different types of alphabets in a string, such as: latin alphabet, katakana, Cyrillic alphabet

Tags: java, regex

I would like to use regex to extract only letters from a string. These letters can come from any type of alphabet.

I want to take a text and remove all symbols that aren't letters (keep spaces). I tired using regex to remove a set of symbols, but it's very inefficient to add all new types of symbols found along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Character.isAlphabetic(int codepoint)` is most likely what you are looking for.

This returns true if `Character.getType(int codepoint)` returns an alphabetic type for the given Unicode codepoint. Since this is Unicode, it will work with other languages. For example, the code:

```
String str = "カタカナ 1234";
IntStream.range(0, str.length())
    .mapToObj(str::charAt)
    .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

gives the output:

```
????
```

Since my console does not know how to print non ascii symbols, it prints question marks (note 4 symbols in the output correspond to 4 input alphabetic characters). However, writing the data to a file it shows the symbols properly.

Note, you may also want to include whitespace for languages that need it (most, but not all, of them), with `Character.isWhitespace(int codepoint)`.

Comment: This seems to be just what I'm looking for, thanks! I forgot to mention that I would still like to keep spaces to distinguish the words, is that possible using this method?

Comment: yes, instead of filtering by Character::isAlphabetic you can replace with a lambda: c -> c.isAlphabetic(c) || c.isWhitespace(c)

Answer (score -1):

You can try looping thru the string and checking the ascii code of each character. 
`A-Z = 65-90 | a-z = 97-122`